# Java DataBase Connectivity Problem with MS SQL Server 2005 from a Remote Server

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, remote-server

I am writing a java code to connect with MS SQL Server 2005. MS SQL Server is on Remote server windows server 2003. I am trying the following code but i am unable to establish a connection:

```
import java.*;

public class Connect {
     private java.sql.Connection con = null;
     private final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
     private final String serverName="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; 
     private final String portNumber = "1433";
     private final String databaseName="myDb"; 
     private final String userName ="user1";
     private final String password = "xxxx";     
     private final String selectMethod = "cursor";

     // Constructor
     public Connect() {}

     private String getConnectionUrl() {
          return url+serverName+":"+portNumber+";databaseName="+databaseName+";selectMethod="+selectMethod+";";
     }

     private java.sql.Connection getConnection() {
          try {
              Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
              con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(),userName,password);
               if(con!=null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
          } catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : " + e.getMessage());
         }
          return con;
      }

     /*
          Display the driver properties, database details
     */

     public void displayDbProperties() {
                    System.out.println("Perform Operations ");

     }

     private void closeConnection() {
          try{
               if(con!=null)
                    con.close();
               con=null;
          }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          Connect myDbTest = new Connect();
         // myDbTest.displayDbProperties();
     }
}
```

But I am getting following exceptions:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
Error Trace in getConnection() : The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Error: No active Connection
```

I am not getting where is the problem in the above code or do i need to do some setting 
to connect to remote server.

Please give me your valuable suggestion which can help me to overcome with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO "Connection refused" means your database server is not visible from your application server.

- Check IP address and port.
- Check database connectivity directly from your database server (to avoid firewalls).
- Check database connectivity from your application server.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your SQL Server is configured to use TCP/IP. Enable it from SQL Server's Network Utility app. Also check there that the SQL Server is using port 1433 (IP Addresses - IPAll - TCP Port).

Try to use "telnet <server_host> 1433". If it doesn't connect you will not be able to establish a connection.

Answer (score 1):

ALLOW THE CONNECTION FIRST IN WHICH PC YOUR SQL SERVER IS RUNNING...
GO TO CONTROL PANEL-->ADMIN. TOOLS--->Windows Firewall with Advanced Security-->Inbounded rules-->new rule-->select port radio button -->next-->enter port 3306-->click next -->finally give the rule name like conn any...click finish